# While evolving Eevee in Pokemon go I am getting an error?

Tags: pokemon-go

While evolving Eevee in Pokemon go I am getting an error.

So i have changed the name of Eevee to Rea and tried to evolve it. Suddenly i got error message "Couldn't evolve Eevee due to an unknown error."

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to solve it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you were attempting to evolve a Party Hat Eevee from the current Pokémon Day event, this seems to be a bug related to it.  See for example [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/fa49ns/useless_info_this_gets_you_that/) reporting the same thing (with Linnea).

Comment: Adding to this, you cannot evolve the Party Hat Eevee. The evolve option was never even there for me.

Comment: The same goes (afaik) for all current Party Hat starters and Pikachu

Comment: @MBorg In my case i have changes the name of eevee and i have changes it to Rea. The Evolve button come. Just getting error while evolving.

Comment: @AkhilPathania The problem is the evolve button *should not* appear.  That's why you get the bug.  The Pokémon isn't evolvable, but it's improperly showing the Evolve button.

Answer (score 9):

This error message typically points to a general network error when contacting the Pokémon Go's servers due to either a bad connection or something happening on Niantic's end.

Restarting the app and reloading Pokémon Go is a good place to start. After you do this, one of two things could happen:

- **It still evolved**: The network blip caused the evolution animation to not appear, thus giving the appearance it didn't evolve. The evolution still occurred in the background, just not visually.
- **It didn't evolve**: The network blip caused an unexpected error when attempting to evolve. It this persists after restarting the app (or getting a better connection), then it's likely something on Niantic's end. You can either wait it out, or [contact support](https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/pokemon-go/?p=web&s=get-in-touch&f=how-to-contact-support)

Comment: This is often the case, but I think it's not the case here, due to the event Eevees.

Comment: @Joe It would seem that you’re correct, and your answer should be the accept one. Given the context (or lack thereof), I was under the assumption the OP was attempting to evolve a regular Eevee. The evolve button doesn’t not appear for me, so this bug didn’t occur to me.

Answer (score -6):

Make sure its not a male Eevee. use a female Eevee and try again

Comment: Eevee is not gender locked, so it being male or female has no bearing on its evolving capabilities.

Comment: So then why is that error coming.

Comment: Even if it were a gender-based evolution (it's not, but in the case of Combee for example), it would remove the Evolve button entirely, rather than displaying an error when you press it.